# Mongoose get all documents where date and number of weeks have current date

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, date-range

I have this type of documents in mongoDB.

```
{
     _id:620df4541571891a71dfa372
     user_id:61cc109f967b757d484fbf3b
     instrument_type:"binance"
     sub_instrument:"BTC/USDT"
     start_date:2022-02-17T00:00:00.000+00:00
     type_quantity:2
     prediction:"High"
     points:12
     price:null
     run_at:null
     createdAt:2022-02-17T07:08:04.633+00:00
     updatedAt:2022-02-17T07:08:04.633+00:00
}
```

Here I have "start_date" which is starting day. "type_quantity" which is number of weeks from start day.

**Example:** If "start_date" is 2022-02-17T00:00:00.000+00:00 and "type_quantity" is 2. Then, the dates per week will become 2022-02-17, 2022-02-24 and 2022-03-03. And If current date is one of these dates then, get this document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [$dateAdd](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateAdd/) in an aggregation query like this:

Note here only is necessary a `$match` stage with `$expr` to get documents where:

- Current date (`$$NOW`) is greater or equal than `$start_date`.
- Current date (`$$NOW`) is lower or equal than calculated date adding X weeks.

i.e. the date found is between `$start_date` and start_date + X weeks.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {
        "$and": [
          {
            "$gte": [
              "$$NOW",
              "$start_date"
            ]
          },
          {
            "$lte": [
              "$$NOW",
              {
                "$dateAdd": {
                  "startDate": "$start_date",
                  "unit": "week",
                  "amount": "$type_quantity"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DvKCtIWydsj) adding more documents.

Comment: Sorry, I think I could not explain my question properly. I have changed it. Please check!

Comment: Thank you for the answer finally, I resolved my issue. It really helped me! Please upvote for better reach.